# Error creating an delete function in a Todo app Redux : TypeError: state.byIds.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a delete_TODO dispatch function in redux and I got an error: "TypeError: state.byIds.filter is not a function"

I don't exactly understand why someone can explain me, I believe its a small stupid thing but I don't see

```js
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  allIds: [],
  byIds: {},
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      const { id, content } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: [...state.allIds, id],
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            content,
            completed: false,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    case TOGGLE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            ...state.byIds[id],
            completed: !state.byIds[id].completed,
          },
        },
      };
    }
   //here is the probleme
    case DELETE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
        byIds: state.byIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your `byIds` property in your initial state is an array type instead of object since `.filter` is not a part of literal object prototype?

```js
const initialState = {
  allIds: [],
  byIds: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

state.byIds is an object not array, filter works on array not object.
you have to make byIds an array. Try this:

```js
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  allIds: [],
  byIds: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      const { id, content } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: [...state.allIds, id],
        byIds: [
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            content,
            completed: false,
          },
        ],
      };
    }
    case TOGGLE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        byIds: [
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            ...state.byIds[id],
            completed: !state.byIds[id].completed,
          },
        ],
      };
    }
   //here is the probleme
    case DELETE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
        byIds: state.byIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not working I don't know why and yes I have a problem ton get to the array.